# Unity JNI ERROR (app bug): global reference table overflow

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, overflow

I have an issue where the app exits with an error in the mobile environment after building with apk in Unity. If you stand still after launching the app, it turns off irregularly for about 10 minutes to 5 days.

Error Log:

---

```
06-19 18:54:20.061 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] JNI ERROR (app bug): global reference table overflow (max=51200)global reference table dump:

06-19 18:54:20.061 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] Last 10 entries (of 51200):

06-19 18:54:20.061 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 51199: 0x6f901170 java.lang.Class<android.app.ApplicationPackageManager>

06-19 18:54:20.061 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 51198: 0x1351afb8 android.app.ApplicationPackageManager

06-19 18:54:20.061 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 51197: 0x1351aff8 java.lang.Class<com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity>

06-19 18:54:20.061 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 51196: 0x13519a78 com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity

06-19 18:54:20.061 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 51195: 0x134fd1e0 java.lang.Class<com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer>

06-19 18:54:20.061 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 51194: 0x6f901170 java.lang.Class<android.app.ApplicationPackageManager>

06-19 18:54:20.061 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 51193: 0x1351afb8 android.app.ApplicationPackageManager

06-19 18:54:20.061 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 51192: 0x1351aff8 java.lang.Class<com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity>

06-19 18:54:20.061 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 51191: 0x13519a78 com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity

06-19 18:54:20.061 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 51190: 0x134fd1e0 java.lang.Class<com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer>

06-19 18:54:20.061 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] Summary:

06-19 18:54:20.061 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 30473 of java.lang.Class (344 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.061 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 10012 of com.google.firebase.MessagingUnityPlayerActivity (1 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.061 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 10008 of android.app.ApplicationPackageManager (1 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.061 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 592 of java.nio.DirectByteBuffer (592 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 18 of java.lang.String (18 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 4 of dalvik.system.PathClassLoader (2 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 4 of java.lang.ref.WeakReference (4 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 4 of android.database.ContentObserver$Transport (4 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 3 of android.opengl.EGLSurface (2 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 3 of android.opengl.EGLContext (2 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 3 of android.opengl.EGLDisplay (2 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 3 of com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzd (3 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 3 of android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$InnerReceiver (3 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 3 of android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$InnerConnection (3 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 2 of android.hardware.display.DisplayManager (1 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 2 of $Proxy3 (2 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 2 of java.lang.ThreadGroup (2 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 2 of dalvik.system.DexClassLoader (2 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 2 of android.os.Handler (2 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 2 of android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$DeathMonitor (2 unique instances)

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of com.google.android.gms.games.internal.zzq

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of com.unity.purchasing.googleplay.GooglePlayPurchasing

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of com.google.games.bridge.InvitationCallbackProxy

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of $Proxy9

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of $Proxy8

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of $Proxy7

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of $Proxy6

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of $Proxy5

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of $Proxy4

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of $Proxy2

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of $Proxy1

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of $Proxy0

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of com.unity3d.player.Camera2Wrapper

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of java.lang.Object

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of dalvik.system.VMRuntime

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.media.MediaRouter

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.media.AudioManager

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.os.Bundle

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.view.Choreographer

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.hardware.input.InputManager

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.util.DisplayMetrics

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.view.SurfaceView

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.os.Binder

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ControlledInputConnectionWrapper

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.os.HandlerThread

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.view.WindowManagerGlobal$1

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.content.ContentProvider$Transport

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.view.KeyCharacterMap

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$IPhoneStateListenerStub

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.view.Display

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.media.MediaRouter$Static$1

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl

06-19 18:54:20.062 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.view.ViewRootImpl$W

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal$DisplayManagerCallback

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.location.LocationManager

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager$1

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.os.PersistableBundle$1

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.hardware.input.InputManager$InputDevicesChangedListener

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.os.Handler$MessengerImpl

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$1

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.view.autofill.AutofillManager$AutofillManagerClient

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of android.media.MediaRouter$Static$Client

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of com.google.android.gms.games.InvitationsClient

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of com.google.android.gms.games.VideosClient

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of com.google.android.gms.games.EventsClient

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of com.google.android.gms.games.TurnBasedMultiplayerClient

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of com.google.android.gms.games.SnapshotsClient

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of com.google.android.gms.games.RealTimeMultiplayerClient

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666] 1 of com.unity3d.player.HFPStatus

06-19 18:54:20.063 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: java_vm_ext.cc:666]

06-19 18:54:20.196 12614 13265 F c.LegendOfAstr: runtime.cc:641] Runtime aborting...
```

Comment: I don't use jni specifically. I don't know where the memory leak occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I could not confirm the cause of the problem, but updating the version from Unity 19.4.0 to 19.4.10 solved the problem.